# Kafka consumer (using kafka-net) fetching all messages from the beginning by default

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I'm building a Kafka consumer for my .net proyect. I'm using kafka-net (A native c# client fro Apache Kafka mady by James Roland).

The problem I have is that this code (based on the documentation) fetches all messages from the beginning by default:

```
private void StartKafkaConsumer(string ipKafka, string portKafka, string topicKafka)
    {
        string topic = topicKafka;
        Uri uri = new Uri($"http://{ipKafka}:{portKafka}");
        var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);


        using (var router = new BrokerRouter(options))
        {
            using (var consumer = new Consumer(new ConsumerOptions(topic, router)))
            {
                foreach (var message in consumer.Consume())
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
StartKafkaConsumer("localhost", "9092", "test");  //this fetches messages sent weeks ago, since the creation of the 'test' topic
```

Basically, this code does the same than this command:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

All I want to do is to fetch messages from the time the client gets connected to the Apache server, not from the beginning. I know it's possible since I tried the last command without the "--from-beginning" part and it worked.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I advise you to use [Confluent Kafka .Net](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) which is up to date with Kafka distro. Last commit in kafka-net is 2.5 year old, it was kafka 0.9.0.1 at this time.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `ConsumerOptions` methods.  There should be an option to set a property/config value:

```
auto.offset.reset
```

Set the above property/config to `latest`.  At that point, anytime you connect with an unknown/new consumer group id, the consumer will default to start at the latest offset.

If, however, the consumer group id was already known (i.e., had already consumed at least once from that topic/partition), it will attempt to get the last committed offset + 1.  If that offset is unavailable, because maybe it has gone past the retention threshold, *then* it will default to latest.

Here's more detailed documentation:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs